# JSP ошибка при подключении к базе данных из Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Есть база данных mysql и сервис, который с ней работает. При запуске кода через метод main из idea все работает. При запуске на tomkat выдает ошибку.

```
Type Exception Report

Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [16]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/index.jsp] at line [16]

13:         IHotelController hotelController=(IHotelController) DependencyService.getDI().getInstance(IHotelController.class);
14:        
15: 
16:            Long guest = hotelController.getGuestSerice().getAllGuestsCount();
17: 
18: 
19:     %>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:142)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

При вызове любого метода, работающего с бд выдает ошибку. А без обращения к mysql работает нормально все. Не понимаю, как выявить причину ошибки, куда смотреть вообще.

Comment: NullPointerException означает что какое-то значение не инициализировано. Например Connection

Comment: Искать NPE.....

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась. Дело в том, что папка с ресурсами была не подключена к maven. Т.е. в собранном проекте не было нужных файлов.
Раньше при запуске проекта из ide задавался относительный путь к папке с ресурсами. В зависимостях maven эта папка не была указана, поэтому в итоговом war-файле их не  было. Нужные классы не создавались.

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/225936)

Comment: @dimka3210, что не так? Как по мне, нормальный ответ. Возможно неисчерпывающий, но всё же ответ.